# Trailhead Superbadge Lightning Experience Specialist - Fulfillment Cancellation Challenge - DML Exception Error

Tags: lightning, trailhead

I could use some guidance here. ? I believe I have all the correct steps for the requirements. However, 'Check Challenge' fails repeatedly with

> "Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: There was an
>   unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check
>   from completing: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception
>   on row 0 with id 0031I000006CwqmQAC; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your
>   attempt to delete Sam the ninja could not be completed because it is
>   associated with the following adventure packages.: null, null : []
>   "

Nothing in the challenge process does any delete operation. Any ideas where this might be coming from ? I guess it may be something deep inside the Trailhead verification system.

Comment: You might check the [Trailhead community group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009Nek) to see if anyone else has run into this.